# Getting grub error 19 after booting

Tags: installation, boot, grub2

I installed ubuntu 11.10, installation completed successfully.
When I remove boot device and restart PC, on loading grub gives "Error 19."

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert the Ubuntu live device and restore GRUB.